# Make few nodes in the datastax cluster slower than the others

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to do a performance testing on datastax's [ChainableLoadBalancingPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/LatencyAwarePolicy.html) and looking for a way to pause few nodes for a while so that latency of those nodes are considered which would make my life easier to compare the results with the current situation when driver doesn't have that implementation. But apparently stop is the only one that comes as a part of DSE service which may be not be as comparing apple with apples.

Is there some obvious way I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: how about use `nodetool drain`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the network emulator mentioned by Adam actually worked for me, so didn't looked into it further. Will keep that in mind to try in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few techniques to do this:

1. Emulate load on the system using something like [cpuburn](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cpuburn.1.html)
2. Emulate large GC pauses by issuing alternating `kill -STOP [pid]` and `kill
   -CONT [pid]` on the server process
3. [Emulate network latencies](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem#Emulating_wide_area_network_delays) using traffic control

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll take a peek and let you know how it goes, appreciate your time and answer.

Comment: the network emulator worked like charm, Thanks Adam